# How does MTR (run with TCP protocol) calculate the loss rate?

Tags: linux, tcp, packet, traceroute

I thought TCP protocol itself will guarantee not to loose any bytes while connecting. About this viewpoint, please refer to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841896/will-tcp-connection-lose-packets

What puzzled me was how mtr (run with TCP protocol) calculate loss? TCP just has segment rather than packets. So, what 'Snt' means?

```
[root@ ~]# mtr --report --tcp --port=443  stackoverflow.com
```

[image]

here, if some of intermediary hosts do not want to reply at all hence Loss% = 100.0, some of them reply ACK hence Loss% = 0.0, then how to explain hops #14 loss% = 25.0%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Analysis

From what I can gather looking over the docs & via Google it looks like `mtr` is tracking packet loss itself by sending traffic and then keeping track of any drops that occur due to network congestion.

For example, the Linode tutorial titled: [Diagnosing Network Issues with MTR](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/diagnostics/diagnosing-network-issues-with-mtr/) states the following:

> The `i` option flag runs the report at a faster rate to reveal packet loss that can occur only during network congestion. This flag instructs MTR to send one packet every n seconds. The default is 1 second, so setting it to a few tenths of a second (0.1, 0.2, etc.) is generally helpful.

The nature of this traffic is ICMP ECHO requests.

```
-i SECONDS
--interval SECONDS

  Use this option to specify the positive number of seconds between ICMP ECHO
  requests. The default value for this parameter is one second.
```

And that method of measuring loss is why you can have loss. `mtr` is not using TCP to measure any loss, it's using ICMP, which can and does have packets that either get dropped or timeout.

#### What about Snt?

The column `Snt` is telling you how many ICMP ECHO packets have been "sent".

Comment: Thanks for your answer and reference. Your answer is quite clear. But I do not fully understand your statement.

Comment: You said "mtr is not using TCP to measure any loss, it's using ICMP...“ . If a router's firewalls block ICMP protocol but TCP is opened. A source host running MTR with TCP mode trace to this router. TCP data transmission is ok. But the source host cannot get ICMP echo from this router,right? Therefore, although the transmission of TCP data is successful, the loss of MTR computing will still show this router has lost TCP data. the scenario is impossible happened?